# Как сделать автосохранение формы?

Tags: angular2

Есть форма

```
<form class="form-user" [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">                                          
    <input formControlName="title" class="title" maxlength="60" />               
    <textarea formControlName="story"></textarea>                
</form>
```

Мне надо реализовать автосохранение данной формы при ее изменении. Код  в `component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(): void { this.userForm.valueChanges.distinctUntilChanged().debounceTime(300).switchMap(data => this.bookDataService.createBook(data)).subscribe(data => {            
    console.log('Form changes', data)
    }) 
        });
```

Но `post` запрос не отправляется при изменение формы и в консоли ничего не происходит. Что в этом коде не так?

Answer (score 0):

я бы повесил обработчик на изменение данных, и пушил по любому изменению:

```
<form class="form-user" [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">                                          
    <input (ngModelChange)="save($event, 'title')" [ngModel]="data.title" formControlName="title" class="title" maxlength="60" />               
    <textarea (ngModelChange)="save($event, 'story')" [ngModel]="data.story" formControlName="story"></textarea>                
</form>
```

и в `component.ts`:

```
data = { title : "title default value", story = "" };
save(value, key) : void {
    this.data[key] = value;
    this.push_to_server_or_local_storage();
}
```